# Remove file present on Linux server

Tags: c#

Trying to run sudo command with  user who has all the priviledges, but something is wrong in my code .

I am trying to remove a file present on the remote server via C# code. It says : The name 'pass' does not exist in the current context.:

My Code :

```
 SshExec sshExec = new SshExec("sj1slm612", "karansha");
            sshExec.Password = "pass";
            sshExec.Connect();

            //Removing config files from sj1slm612 server

            string remove_config_file_express = "echo " + "'" + pass + "'" + "| sudo -S -u wtsnqa rm " + "/apps/instances/express_13000/configuration/standalone-full.xml";
            string output_express = sshExec.RunCommand(remove_config_file_express);
 Console.WriteLine("All config files removed");
            Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Please make yourself familiar with the difference between compiler and runtime errors. The way you fix them is different.

Answer (score 1):

the compiler is indeed correct. you reference a variable called pass which you probably meant to be the string "pass"

```
 string remove_config_file_express = "echo " + "'" + pass + "'" + "| sudo -S -u wtsnqa rm " + "/apps/instances/express_13000/configuration/standalone-full.xml";
```

Answer (score 0):

Use tamir Library next code.

```
    public static bool BorrarArchivo(string rutaRemota) 
    {


        try
        {
            SshExec comando = new SshExec(Servidor, Usuario);
            comando.Password = Password;

            comando.Connect();

            string paso = comando.RunCommand("rm " + rutaRemota);

            comando.Close();

            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            mErrorSFTP = ex.Message;
            return false;
        }

    }
```